# Blackberry Drag And Drop (RAD) GUI Design

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Android got XML layout design with a tool that allow you to drop and drag GUI design. Can I have something similar for creating a GUI for a Blackberry application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no tools that do this for Blackberry development.

There used to be a plugin for Visual Studio that would do this, but it's been discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

[DragonRAD](http://www.dragonrad.com/) is a new tool was just announced. They are currently accepting applications for a closed beta.  Invitations won't be sent out for a few more weeks, so I can't comment on how well it performs.